# ¿Como recibir un JSON en mi pagina web PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, json, arduino, postman

Soy bastante nuevo en PHP y estoy buscando la mejor manera de recibir un JSON en mi pagina web por medio de PHP. Este JSON lo estoy enviando desde un arduino o desde un metodo post en Postman pero necesito poder visualizar y almacenar los datos que vienen en el JSON. Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Lo solucionaste @alec_ ?

Comment: Aún no lo he solucionado

Answer (score 0):

Lo haría con [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
    $json_url = URI_DE_TUS_DATOS;
    $json = file_get_contents($json_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

podrías probar para recoger el json de la siguiente forma (espero que te sea útil):

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true); 
var_dump($data);
```

- file_get_contents("php://input") -> La función "file_get_contents" transmite un fichero a una cadena y "php://input" es un flujo de sólo lectura que permite leer datos de peticiones POST.
- json_decode -> Permite decodificar un json y la opción "true" es para transformar ese objeto json a un array asociativo php.